# TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable, while loop in a for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop, scrapy, typeerror

I'm coding in Python and try to learn about scrapy things...

I keep having always the same error when I run my code but I don't understand why...
Here's my code :

```
    avgcost_tot = response.xpath('//div[@class="jsFacetListing mgFacetListing mgFOpen"][1]/div[@class="mgFAllList"][1]/ul/li/label/span/text()').re(r'\<?(.*[\d]*)\€+')

    if (len(avgcost_tot) != 0):
        avgcost = [avgcost_tot[i].split(' ') for i in range(len(avgcost_tot))]
        for i in range(len(avgcost)):
            avgcost[i].remove(avgcost[i][1])
        for i in range(1,len(avgcost)-1):
            avgcost[i].remove(avgcost[i][2])
            while avgcost[i] != '':
                avgcost[i] = int(sum(list(map(int, avgcost[i])))/len(avgcost[i]))
```

I have a lot of lines before and after these but I know my error comes from here.
The error is : `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`...

Is there someone to help me with this please?

Comment: "but I think my error comes from here" => don't "think" - the error message and traceback tell you exactly (file and line number) where the exception was raised, so use this information. At least post the full traceback and the relevant part of the code.

Comment: I "think" is just a word. I know that because the entire error message is : `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable` at this line `avgcost[i] = int(sum(list(map(int, avgcost[i])))/len(avgcost[i]))`

Comment: then why saying "I think" and not clearly stating that the error is at this exact line ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here :

```
avgcost[i] = int(sum(list(map(int, avgcost[i])))/len(avgcost[i]))
```

and more exactly here:

```
map(int, avgcost[i])
```

you pass an integer to `map()`. Well, at the second iteration of the while loop at least it's an integer (as a result of the first iteration).

While we're at it, this loop would probably be infinite if it didn't raised, since an int is not going to equal the empty string. Actually I don't see the point of a `while` loop here.

Also, you don't need to pass the result of `map()` to `list` - in Python2 it will already be a `list`, and in Python3 it will be an iterable that can be passed directly to `sum()`. And since a sum of integers will be an integer, passing the result of `sum()` to `int()` is pretty useless too.

Comment: Thank you, I will change everything and come back to you!!